# Cannot match sitemap route - Angular application hosted on AWS Amplify

Tags: angular, typescript, aws-amplify, angular-routing, sitemap

I am unable to navigate to my sitemap.xml file because of this error. I am able to access the XML locally but not after deploying.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sitemap.xml'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sitemap.xml'
```

**These are my routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      component: LandingComponent,
    
    },
    {
      path: 'sitemap.xml',
      redirectTo: 'assets/sitemap.xml',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    }];
```

I've also tried setting the rule in Amplify's Rewrites and redirects.